# Formatting month names as alphabets

Tags: php

I am trying to create an associative array that will parse an alphabet for each month name. e.g JAN - A, FEB - B, MAR - C... I need some help for this. I have done a lot of searching but not able to. Can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$my_month = date('m');
$months = array("JAN"=>"A",
            "FEB"=>"B",
            "MAR"=>"C",
            "APR"=>"D",
            "MAY"=>"E",
            "JUN"=>"F",
            "JUL"=>"G",
            "AUG"=>"H",
            "SEP"=>"I",
            "OCT"=>"J",
            "NOV"=>"K",
            "DEC"=>"L" );

if ($my_month == date('M')) {
  echo $months[$my_month];
  } else {
  echo 'almost there';
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? How would you like to parse it if there was an array like this? I mean what the code would be?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to sort the array based on the current month and have the code output the corresponding letter for the month in a textfield. I have thought about using an if...else statement but the sysntax is what i am having trouble with. am a php newbie

Comment: given no code (equivalent to feet) makes this impossible to outfit you with the right pair of shoes, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Thanks Thanasis, I appreciate the good work. I have tried the following. Maybe you can me figure out why its not working. I am trying to output the current month as a letter based on comparing the current month against its match with the values in the array. My code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need to create an array as you want is this:

```
$months['1'] = 'A';
$months['2'] = 'B';
$months['3'] = 'C';
$months['4'] = 'D';
$months['5'] = 'E';
$months['6'] = 'F';
$months['7'] = 'G';
$months['8'] = 'H';
$months['9'] = 'I';
$months['10'] = 'J';
$months['11'] = 'K';
$months['12'] = 'L';
```

Or even better:

```
$months = array("1"=>"A",
                "2"=>"B",
                "3"=>"C",
                "4"=>"D",
                "5"=>"E",
                "6"=>"F",
                "7"=>"G",
                "8"=>"H",
                "9"=>"I",
                "10"=>"J",
                "11"=>"K",
                "12"=>"L" );
```

And let's say the `$my_month` variable has the month (in the form 'JAN', 'FEB', ...) from which you want to get the corresponding letter. This is what you write to get the letter:

```
echo $months[$my_month];
```

Comment: Thanks Thanasis, I appreciate the good work. I have tried the following. Maybe you can me figure out why its not working. I am trying to output the current month as a letter based on comparing the current month against its match with the values in the array.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the code above.

Comment: Thanasis! I solved it following your principle. I studied the error I was getting after running the code above and discovered that I just needed to substitute the month names to numbers and it worked! can you please edit your code or should i re-edit my code above?

Comment: You mean this: JAN->1, FEB->2 , ... ?

Comment: Close, I mean "1"=>"A","2"=>"B". I'll need you to edit your code so that i can score you for providing the correct answer. I wouldn't have figured it out if you didn't help me.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much ! I will do it in a few minutes !

Comment: It's done. I'm glad Icould help :)